# Executing code after if/else

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

Question around executing something after it comes after an if-statement.
How do I get this code to return "i love wombats" despite whatever if/else result happens? ie. I want to return "i love wombats" every time this runs.

```
def is_wombats(x):
    if x.lower() == "wombat":
        return "yay wombats"
    else:
        return "no wombats"
    return "i love wombats"

print is_wombats("WOMbat")
```

TLDR: why isn't the return statement after if/else executing?

Comment: The `return` statements in the `if` end the function. Nothing executes after `return`.

Comment: 1. Do you understand how `if/else` works??? 2. Do you know what exactly you want to return in every scenario?

Comment: The better question is if he understands how `return` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return will exit the current function, what I think that you are looking for is something like this:

```
>>> def is_wombats(x):
...     if x.lower() == "wombat":
...         print "yay wombats"
...     else:
...         print "no wombats"
...     print "I love wombats"
...
>>> is_wombats("WOMbat")
yay wombats
I love wombats
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with what `return` does. It ends the function. Nothing else will be run after you `return` something. If you want to return `'I love wombats'` every time, this is not the right way of doing it.

Comment: I did not realize that about return ending the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
def is_wombats(x):
    if x.lower() == "wombat":
        result = "yay wombats"
    else:
        result = "no wombats"
    return result + " i love wombats"
```

then

```
>>> print is_wombats("WOMbat")
"yay wombats i love wombats"
```